# Does glDrawBuffers() / glReadBuffer() define a global state?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

For Example when I do:

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)
```

Does I have to call it on a per frame buffer basis or is it a global state for every frame buffer? The documentation is not clear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [GL 3.3 core profile spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.pdf) (section 4.2.1 "Selecting a buffer for writing"):

> The state required to handle color buffer selection for each framebuffer is an
>   integer for each supported fragment color.

This is a per-framebuffer state. Note that you *never* have to set any state *per frame* in OpenGL, as OpenGL does not even have a concept of a "frame".

Comment: So when I rebind the frame buffer I do not call glDrawBuffer() again unless I want to change it?

Comment: @Alexander: well. you do not need to, at least ;)